# MySQL - Persistent Connections

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am currently running a web application with thousands of visitors and users connecting at the same time. I have a lot of "sleeping" connections in WHM (like 50-65).

I think I am using persistent connections, but my question is, how can I disable this?

This is how I connect to the database:

```
$dbh = null;
$class = 'PDO';
$database = $settings['database']; //Get the database login information. It is stored in an array();

global $database;

try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $database['host'] . ";dbname=" . $database['db'];
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $database['user'], $database['pass'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));        
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
    //echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I keep getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections
```

Even though I have updated the `max_connections` in `my.cnf` to `5000`

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: `I think I am using persistent connections, but my question is, how can I disable this?` think it has anything to do with -> `array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)` .. ? and a persistent connection is not closed when the script has run.

Comment: In case you haven't searched elsewhere, this link may be useful: [2013/11/28/mysql-error-too-many-connections/](http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/11/28/mysql-error-too-many-connections/). It mentions 'sleeping connections' and possibly other useful links. Internet search: 'mysql Too many connections'.